# Non Renewable Subscription iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I am creating non renewable subscription for one of my application.

I have read document that if I implement non renewable subscription then I have to write code to expire it from server side.

I am all done with it.

But I am little bit confuse that If I am going to purchase that item once its expired the alert says as attached in image. That means it will restore the non renewable subscription or it will purchase a new one?

[image]

Also another question I have read that on stackoverflow that If application is providing non renewable sunscription that it must has optional registration flow is it true?

Comment: The user will be charged again.  Non renewing subscriptions can't be restored.  It is highly recommended that you give the user the opportunity to create an account so that they can use their subscription on a new or different device.

Comment: @Paulw11 We have already user registration feature in application but this is mandatory to use app So I am confirming that is it mandatory that we provide registration flow optional for the user in order to purchase non-renewal subscription?

Comment: You may have issues with app review with mandatory user registration; it is nothing to do with subscriptions.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok thanks...

Answer (score 2):

About your **first question**, non-renewing subscriptions can not be restored or sync via the usual Apple way of providing restoring/syncing between devices. You have to provide your own mechanism.
You can check [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase) and judge yourself how you want to do it.

> You can sync and restore non-consumables and auto-renewable
> subscriptions across devices using StoreKit. When a user purchases an
> auto-renewable or non-renewing subscription, your app is responsible
> for making it available across all the user's devices, and for
> enabling users to restore past purchases.

Regarding your **second question**:

You can check how your app relates to the following entry in the [review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#introduction).

> "**(v) Account Sign-In**: If your app doesn’t include significant
> account-based features, let people use it without a log-in. Apps may
> not require users to enter personal information to function, except
> when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or
> required by law. If your core app functionality is not related to a
> specific social network (e.g. Facebook, WeChat, Weibo, Twitter, etc.),
> you must provide access without a login or via another mechanism.
> Pulling basic profile information, sharing to the social network, or
> inviting friends to use the app are not considered core app
> functionality. The app must also include a mechanism to revoke social
> network credentials and disable data access between the app and social
> network from within the app. An app may not store credentials or
> tokens to social networks off of the device and may only use such
> credentials or tokens to directly connect to the social network from
> the app itself while the app is in use."