# iOS Non-Renewable subscription

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I am trying to implement a non-renewable subscription in my swift app. Everything works fine until the first time purchase the subscription. Then the app will set the expiry date and use iCloud to sync/restore.

When I try to re-purchase (on sandbox for now) It will not even open the purchasing sheets but directly point me to purchase completion delegate methods, which is fine. Cos I can get the transaction date and re-calculate and set expiry date if needed. In this scenario the message I get is:

`<Google>[I-ACS02****] Purchase is a duplicate and will not be reported. Product ID: com.xxx.xx.xxx`.

Which looks reasonable. But the issue is since Apple doesn't know anything about my expiry dates how can I actually renew if a user actually wants to renew it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822843/non-renewable-subscription-ios) says it'll show an alert asking to renew or extend, which I don't see today.

So I have two questions;

1. How to renew when a subscription is expired. (I only tested on sandbox for now)
2. Why is that `<Google>` tag appears on the apple message?

I didn't add any codes, since all the codes are the basic purchase flow for simple in-app purchases, and some more codes to manage expiry date.

Comment: It says "Google" because you're using Firebase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987610/firebase-error-when-doing-iap